# Gradle building unused dependencies

Tags: java, gradle, build, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies

When using Gradle as a build tool for Android Projects like normally, does Gradle always build everything from a given dependency, or does it only build the things inside the dependency that you are using, together with the dependencies that these things might have underneath ?

Does it skip building things that you are not using?

Answer (score 0):

You have to build a gradle to fit that version of Android or to use api. I understand that it is not possible to omit the gradle build.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think I understand what you are saying but it is not that I want to omit the gradle build as a whole. It should do the gradle build just like normal, but I need to know if a gradle build will skip artifacts of a dependency when the artifacts are not used in the application. In other words, does it build the total dependency on every gradle build, or just the used artifacts of that dependency ? @J.JH

Comment: I know that we are building a full dependence on all gradients.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, all code from a dependency is included in the build (.apk file).

*Unless you turn on tools that minimize or remove unused files / classes / functions.* For more on that subject: [minimize code](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code).